# Printing array with Processingjs

Tags: javascript, processing.js

[image]

I'm reading through the khan academy course on algorithms. I'm at https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/sorting-algorithms/p/project-selection-sort-visualizer .

The code is working and I can get it to print to the console but I need to be able to print to the canvas.

I've tried :

```
var displayArray = function(array) {
    textFont(createFont("monospace"), 12);
    println(array);

};
```

Bu this again just prints to the console. How can I print to the canvas with processingjs?

Comment: https://processing.org/tutorials/text/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Specifically, add this to `displayArray()`:

```
textAlign(LEFT, TOP);
fill(0);
print(array);
text(array, 0, 0);
```

Or if you want it centered:

```
textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
fill(0);
print(array);
text(array, 200, 200);
```

Comment: Thank you. This brings up a question, I don't know anything about canvas elements but do they range from 0-400 in both x and y dimensions?

Comment: @user61629 yes, you are correct. `0, 0` is the upper-left, `400, 400` is the bottom-right.

Answer (score 1):

You're still using "println", you need to use 'text' function.

http://processingjs.org/reference/text_/ is the reference on how to use this.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
var myArray = [1,2,3];
var displayArray = function(array) {
   textFont(createFont("monospace"), 12);
   text(array, 5, 20);
}
var draw = function {
   displayArray(myArray);
}
```

Comment: Please try to avoid pasting just code, and add an explanation as to how your code provides a solution. Welcome to stackoverflow.